What should we use as Primary Key and how does it relate to Send Relationship
At the moment our SFMC account uses Email Address as the Primary Key for all of our data extensions. We also always set up the Send Relationship as Email address relates to Email address. I've run into several problems with using Email address - some customers share email addresses (married couples), email addresses can change in a customer's lifetime and some customers don't have one, only a mobile number that we want to contact through SMS instead. I have a few options to change this.

I use Customer Number. This is unique and is the best way to track customer activity across all our systems and would ensure I can follow their lifetime journey. However, this doesn't exist for Prospects until they become customers, so I would need something else for them.
I generate a Subscriber Id for everyone. However, this would make tracking customers across our other systems, as it would only relate to SFMC. I would need to refer back to Customer Number to get the full information.

Should I pick one Primary Key and stick to it, or could have different ones for different customer groups?
I also don't understand how I would set up send relationship if I switched to using one of the above as primary key. Would it still be based on email address for tracking unsubscribes?

Primary Key has as such nothing to do with your send relationship. PK is mainly an indicator of which field in your data extension should be the unique one, a requirement in case you want to update a specific record on e.g. CSV file upload. A primary key CAN be the same field as your subscriber key (e.g. in an audience data extension), but not necessarily. In case of a data extension listing all the orders, the primary key will be the order number. Same person can have made multiple purchases, meaning their subscriber key will be listed multiple times in the same data extension. More on primary keys here.
Now that we have made a clear distinction between PK and SK, let's address the best practices concerning a subscriber key. It should IMHO be:

Unique
Persistent
Channel agnostic
Global

I am writing much more about this in my article, but let me recommend you for sure, that having email as SK is a really bad idea, as you have also figured out. An email is not channel agnostic.
As you have also figured out, using your own key in SFMC will not make it global. You want indeed to have all your systems having same ID for your subscribers. Otherwise you will have hard time mapping all these IDs to each other.
If possible, I will recommend you to investigate the option of assigning customer ID to your prospects as well. This could be a user profile with a flag specifying their prospect status. Once they turn into actual customers, this flag can change. It will ensure the persistent nature of this ID.
This is obviously highly dependent on your enterprise architecture, and specifically on the system of record of your customer data. Not knowing anything in details, makes it impossible for us to provide you with the right answer. Teaming up with a skilled architect in your company will for sure point you towards the right solution.
